# Localization SLAM how to do?

Tags: ros, slam, localization, navigation, teb-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I try to develop an autonomous driving car. The problem is that I don't know how to localize the car on my SLAM map.

I only use a LiDAR UTM-30LX LiDAR to navigate. I created successfully a SLAM map with hector mapping.

Now I want to estimate a start point and a goal. I use the navigation stack with move base to navigate. As local planner I have implemented the teb_local_planner because of the Ackermann steering.
I can estimate a start point and can set a goal. I also can forward my cmd_vel to the car with a steering angle and a speed info. But the position of the robot on the map in rviz don't change.

Can you help me and tell me what I have to do? I can't start playing around to find a good config for the teb_local_planner like this :(

Here is my launch file:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="urg_node" type="urg_node" name="urg_node">
    <param name="ip_address" type="string" value="192.168.0.10"/>
  </node>
  <param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="true"/>
  <param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
  <param name="base_frame" value="base_frame"/>
  <param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="map_2_odom" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /map /odom 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_2_base_footprint" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /odom /base_footprint 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_footprint_2_base_link" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_footprint /base_link 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_2_base_stabilized_link" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /base_stabilized 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_stablized_2_base_frame" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_stabilized /base_frame 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_frame_2_laser_link" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_frame /laser 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_2_nav_link" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_frame /nav 100"/>
  <node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl"/>
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find autonomous_car)/launch/costmaps/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find autonomous_car)/launch/costmaps/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find autonomous_car)/launch/costmaps/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find autonomous_car)/launch/costmaps/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find autonomous_car)/launch/costmaps/teb_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load"/>
    <param name="clearing_rotation_allowed" value="false"/>
  </node>
  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" args="-d $(find hector_slam_example)/launch/rviz_cfg.rviz"/>
</launch>
```

My amcl_pose dont update, but the car is moving with the speed and angle from the first input :/

rostopic echo /amcl_pose

header:

seq: 0

stamp:

```
secs: 1484760781

nsecs: 434161143
```

frame_id: map

pose:

pose:

```
position: 

  x: 1.50654940711

  y: 3.46721180218

  z: 0.0

orientation: 

  x: 0.0

  y: 0.0

  z: -0.773900494384

  w: 0.633307212016
```

covariance: [0.18227685925353398, 0.0027654181834790847, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0027654181834790847, 0.22445548719072939, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.06599867634852088]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252130/localization-slam-how-to-do?/) by [FelixF](https://answers.ros.org/users/28568/felixf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-01-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-17**:
Not a navigation expert, but I see static TF publishers for important transforms such as `/map` to `/odom` and `/odom` and `/base_footprint`. That seems strange to me, because how do you expect your localisation (you are running one, right?) to update the position of your robot that way?

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2017-01-17**:
following on @gvdhoorn, are you running AMCL?

**Comment by [FelixF](https://answers.ros.org/users/28568/felixf/) on 2017-01-17**:
So I set the init pose and I set a goal, then the Path the Robot should drive appears. the echo of cmd_vel contains good values. But if I start moving arround the LiDAR the ArrowCloud won't get smaler and also the polygon of the robot does not move

**Comment by [FelixF](https://answers.ros.org/users/28568/felixf/) on 2017-01-17**:
I think I have to reconfigure my whole tf tree... But I don't get it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you should use [AMCL](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl).
it is THE node for localization in ROS.
And, as mentioned by @gvdhoorn, you should not publish the tf between `/map` and `/odom`, because that is exactly what you want to be published by a localization algoritm (follow the link above on AMCL and check the illustrations on the bottom of the page).

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2017-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FelixF](https://answers.ros.org/users/28568/felixf/) on 2017-01-17**:
please check my comment on top. You are right I deleted this tf, but the porblem is still alive :/

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2017-01-18**:
what exactly is your problem? what is the output of the AMCL node?

**Comment by [FelixF](https://answers.ros.org/users/28568/felixf/) on 2017-01-18**:
The Problem is that the position of the car shown in rviz don't update, allthough the car is moving

I aded the amcl_pose to the question

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2017-01-23**:
so your amcl pose does not change at all while moving the robot? is it subscribing to the correct scan topic?